# Menu in child process inside a tab not shown on mouse click

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a chrome like application. I do have two applications Say Parent and Child Application. Child application contains menus. When i am attaching an instance of child application to a tab of parent application. Menu in child application is not shown on mouse click.

Code snippet used for attaching process is

```
Process P = Process.GetProcessesByName("Child");
P.WaitForInputIdle();
IntPtr handle = P.MainWindowHandle;
SetParent(handle, this.tabPage1.Handle);
MoveWindow(handle, rec.X, rec.Y, rec.Width, rec.Height, true);
```

I cannot make any changes to Child application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few research, i was able to find out the solution.

Solution

Before calling SetParent, We should update the window style using SetWindowLongPtr of Windows API.
Final code will be as follows

```
        long style = WinAPI.GetWindowLongPtr(new HandleRef(this,console.MainWindowHandle), WinAPIConstants.GWL_STYLE).ToInt64();

        style= style & ~(WinAPIConstants.WS_CAPTION |
                                        WinAPIConstants.WS_BORDER |
                                        WinAPIConstants.WS_DLGFRAME);
        IntPtr styleValue = new IntPtr(style);
        Rectangle displayRectangle = newTab.DisplayRectangle;

        // Removing the title bar and border.
        WinAPI.SetWindowLongPtr(new HandleRef( this,console.MainWindowHandle),
                              WinAPIConstants.GWL_STYLE, styleValue);

        style = WinAPI.GetWindowLongPtr(new HandleRef(this, console.MainWindowHandle), WinAPIConstants.GWL_STYLE).ToInt64();
        style &= ~WinAPIConstants.WS_POPUP;
        style |= WinAPIConstants.WS_CHILD;

        styleValue = new IntPtr(style);

        // Setting window to be child of current application and the popup behaviour of window is removed.
        WinAPI.SetWindowLongPtr(new HandleRef(this, console.MainWindowHandle), WinAPIConstants.GWL_STYLE, styleValue);

        // Attach the console to the tab. 
        WinAPI.SetParent(console.MainWindowHandle, newTab.Handle);
```

Thank you

Vipin Kumar Mallaya.

Answer (score 0):

As per MSDN:

"Use WaitForInputIdle() to force the processing of your application to wait until the message loop has returned to the idle state. When a process with a user interface is executing, its message loop executes every time a Windows message is sent to the process by the operating system. The process then returns to the message loop. A process is said to be in an idle state when it is waiting for messages inside of a message loop. This state is useful, for example, when your application needs to wait for a starting process to finish creating its main window before the application communicates with that window.

If a process does not have a message loop, WaitForInputIdle() throws an InvalidOperationException.

The WaitForInputIdle() overload instructs the Process component to wait indefinitely for the process to become idle in the message loop. This instruction can cause an application to stop responding. For example, if the process is written to always exit its message loop immediately, as in the code fragment while(true)."

Therefore, I think you should consider commenting `P.WaitForInputIdle();`

Comment: I am able to attach the process to my tab; My problem is with menu not with attaching process. For an attached Child process(Which is a .net based application), Menu is not shown on mouse click.

Comment: Exactly, Menu is not shown because child has entered idle state.